# meta-qt5 do_populate_sdk does not create qmake on yocto zeus

Tags: c++, qt5, yocto, qmake, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm trying to create cross-compiling tools for my c++ application to compile it and push binaries to arm64 device (jetson-nano) during image building. I've added `inherit populate_sdk_qt5` line to my own recipe and `bitbake -c populate_sdk <my-recipe>`. I've got no errors so I run `.sh` file I've got as an output. It works fine but I cannot find `qmake` in destination path (tried with `find ./ -name 'qmake'` without any output). Have you ever had similar situation? Do you have some advice for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to sync your meta-tegra. There was an update just a few days ago.